# Is there a possibility to "revive" buttons after .destroy()?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am programming a game in Python and for this I want to have some buttons in tkinter that I can destroy and "revive" after this from another button click. Is it possible to "revive" destroyed Buttons?

I´ve tried to grid the Buttons again, but that didn't work.

```py
def btnclick(event):
    b1.destroy()
def revive(event):
    b1.grid(row=0, column=4)
b1 = Button(root)
b2 = Button(root)
b1.bind("<Button-1>", btnclick)
b2.bind("<Button-1>", revive)
b1.grid(row=0, column=4)
b2.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

I thought that would put the button back on the screen, but I only get this error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".47822896"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'revive' an object that was destroyed; you can either re-create it, or, better yet, you can remove it from the GUI layout using `grid_forget`, and re-insert it later using the geometry manager `grid`.

here is a short example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hide_b1():
    b1.grid_forget()

def show_b1():
    b1.grid(row=0, column=4)

root = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='b1', command=hide_b1)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='b2', command=show_b1)
show_b1()
b2.grid(row=1, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Please note that `tk.Buttons` have an attribute `command` that you should take advantage of, and use, instead of custom bindings to events.